# Sound from 'ms-winsoundevent' scheme not played on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I develop UWP app with notifications. I want to set custom sound from *winsoundevent* scheme for them. On desktop version it works fine, but on mobile sound not played. How to play this sounds on mobile version?  Code for investigating:

```
 RingtoneMediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm7", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
 RingtoneMediaElement.AutoPlay = true;
 RingtoneMediaElement.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ms-winsoundevent` is one of the [Toast schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230849.aspx). So this scheme is used in a toast content with an [`audio`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230842.aspx) tag like `<audio src="ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Mail" loop="false"/>`.

I don't find any official documents said about this scheme can be supported as a media source for media element. In my mind, we should not use it as a media source although it can be played in local machine.

For your requirements to set custom sound for notifications, this scheme can work, sample code as follows:

```
private void btnpushnotification_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string xml= $@"
                    <toast scenario='incomingCall'>
                      <visual>
                        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
                          <text>Looping Audio Toast</text>
                          <text>This toast uses looping audio, useful for scenarios like phone calls.</text>
                        </binding>
                      </visual>
                      <actions>
                        <action arguments = 'answer' content = 'answer' />
                        <action arguments = 'ignore' content = 'ignore' />
                      </actions>
                       <audio src='ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm7' loop='true'/>
                    </toast>";
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    var toast = new ToastNotification(doc);
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
}
```

I tested this sample on mobile emulator and Lumia 640, windows 10 build 14393. Both of them worked well. Additionally, for custom sound,there is a known issue on previous windows phone OS mentioned in [this article](http://%20Also%20this%20is%20a%20known%20issue%20in%20the%20previous%20windows%20phone%20version%20mentioned%20in%20[this%20document][3]):

> ...custom audio isn't working. We're investigating this issue. As of now, both ms-appx and ms-appdata don't work on Desktop, and only ms-appdata works on Mobile.

More details about this known issue and how to resolve please reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059873/uwp-custom-toast-notification-sound-doesnt-play-on-mobile).

More details about the sample code please reference the [Audio scenario](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications/cs/Notifications/ScenarioPages/Toasts/Audio) of [notification official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications).

Comment: The ms-winsoundevent: sounds work fine on Desktop. Not so on Mobile. As for the custom audio issue on Mobile, that has been fixed since the first RTM build of Mobile which is 10586 and works just fine. The issue Boris is having is a known issue reported here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ff0cfe88-3207-426c-817f-ca4eb19aeae9/uwpxamlcno-audio-playback-on-windows-mobile-version-1511-and-redstone-builds-when?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: @Abdousamad Please check my reply. Sounds work fine on desktop but not on mobile is true, but this is not a right use for this scheme. As I mentioned in my reply, the known issue is on *previous* os version, for new build 14393 I tested notification with this scheme it is worked both on phone and desktop. This has resolved the custom sound in *notification*  issue. For the same  thread in MSDN you posted here it is not moved to the `known issue` forum we can not determine it is a known issue. It you just  want to report a bug please go to windows 10 feed back tool. Thanks for understanding.